# How do I filter an array of sentences starting with the same word and create a new array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code right now. I already have an array of sentences, which is the `userTimeline`. What I am trying to do is filter the `userTimeline` array with sentences that start with Aquarius and extract those into a new array. How do I do that?

```
    var userTimeline = [];

    var params = {
        screen_name: "ZodiacFacts"
    };

    cb.__call(
    "statuses_userTimeline",
    params,

    function (reply, rate, error){
        //console.log(reply);
        for(var i = 0; i < reply.length; i++){
            userTimeline.push(reply[i].text);
        }
        console.log(userTimeline);
    }
    );
```

Comment: Have you considered the [array `.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which lets you do exactly what you're asking in one line of code?

Comment: I see examples using numbers, not sure how to do that with words

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I think your array of sentences is "reply" and new array that you want to create is userTimeline. Now as @dhilt mentioned, you should use filter.

```
var userTimeline = [];

var params = {
    screen_name: "ZodiacFacts"
};

cb.__call(
"statuses_userTimeline",
params,

function (reply, rate, error){

    userTimeline = reply.filter(function (value) {
        return /^Aquarius/i.test(value);
    });
}
);

console.log(userTimeline);  // This array has all the sentences which starts with 'Aquarius'
```

Comment: And how would I store this into a new array?

Comment: log userTimeline after above code - console.log(userTimeline);

userTimeline in your new array and it has all the sentences which starts with "Aquarius". I have updated my code.